# How to update default values from http.Request elegantly?

Tags: go

I'm doing book gopl's exercise 1.12, Basically, the code need to update several default values from http.Request if it is present in URL parameters.

Say here is the code I'm working on:

```golang
var ( // Need to update those values if corresponding parameter present in URL
    cycles = 5
    res    = 0.001
    size   = 100
)
```

I can do the updating one by one:

```golang
if c := r.FormValue("cycles"); c != "" { // r is a *http.Request
    i, err := strconv.ParseInt(c); err != nil {
        cycles = i
    }
}

if r := r.FormValue("res"); r != "" {
    if f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(r); err != nil {
        res = f
    }
}

// ...
```

But I'm not satisfied by this solution:

- If I have dozens of params, this is very cumbersome
- How to handle the conversion errors?

The repeating pattern seems requires a function, like this (I don't know how to implement it yet, just showing my thought)

```golang
func setParam(p interface{}, name string, r *http.Request) error {
    if f := r.FormValue(name); f != "" {
        switch p.(type) {
        case int:
            // strconv.ParseInt
        case float64:
            // strconv.PraseFloat
        // ...
    }
}
```

This looks better, but still cumbersome. I don't know if this is the best solution. Or I overlooked some feature in Go that should be used in this situation.

So, what's the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Your second solution is not necessarily more elegant. If you need to do things to dozens of things, you have to do dozens of things.

Comment: Then what's the point of functions? If I'm doing dozens of similar things?

Comment: Your second solution doesn't work. `p` will *always* be `*string`, because that's the type of the param. The type switch doesn't work. As to "How to handle the conversion errors?", that's completely implementation-dependent: you should handle them appropriately for the needs of your application.

Comment: You will still have to call the function dozens of times. You can find a declarative way of processing such parameters using reflection and tags, or use a map of functions to tie parameter names to conversion functions.

Comment: @BurakSerdar You're right. Thanks for pointing the right direction.

Comment: I wrote such things before. The perceived elegance diminishes in time as edge cases that don't fit into the pattern increase.

Answer (score 1):

Write functions that get a form value as a specific type or return default when value is missing.  Example:

```
func intValue(r *http.Request, name string, def int) (int, error) {
    if _, ok := r.Form[name]; !ok {
        return def, nil
    }
    return strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue(name))
}
```

Call these functions from your handler. This is repetitive like the code in the question, but combines variable declaration, default value and fetching value in a single line of code.

```
    cycles, err := intValue(r, "cycles", 5)
    if err != nil {
        // TODO; handle bad value
    }
```